# Working with audio in Java

Tags: java, audio, javasound, mixer

I went over Java's tutorial on sounds but somehow it is way too complex for a beginner.
It is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html)
My aim is this:

Detect all the audio input and output devices

let the user select a audio **input** device

capture what the user says

output it to the **default** audio output device

Now how do I go about doing that?
Is there a better tutorial available?
**What I have tried:**

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
public class SoundTrial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mixer.Info[] info = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
        int i =0;
        for(Mixer.Info print : info){

            System.out.println("Name: "+ i + " " + print.getName());
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
Name: 0 Primary Sound Driver
Name: 1 Speakers and Headphones (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)
Name: 2 Independent Headphones (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC
Name: 3 SPDIF (Digital Out via HP Dock) (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC)
Name: 4 Primary Sound Capture Driver
Name: 5 Integrated Microphone Array (ID
Name: 6 Microphone (IDT High Definition
Name: 7 Stereo Mix (IDT High Definition
Name: 8 Port Speakers and Headphones (IDT Hi
Name: 9 Port SPDIF (Digital Out via HP Dock)
Name: 10 Port Integrated Microphone Array (ID
Name: 11 Port Microphone (IDT High Definition
Name: 12 Port Stereo Mix (IDT High Definition
Name: 13 Port Independent Headphones (IDT Hi
```

Comment: *"Java's tutorial on sounds but somehow it is way too complex for a beginner."*  In which language is sound 'easy'?

Comment: +1 the tutorials are aimed at people with some experience. Tutorials should be like this http://www.javatutorialhub.com/timers-java

Comment: if that is to complicated i doubt any other tutorial will be better. I suggest you just try and see where you get. Your step 1 to detect is clearly decribed. just run the code.

if the code fails then come back and ask more specific quetsions

Comment: Maybe this is more what you are looking for: http://www.jsresources.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code may help you. Note this has been taken from this link: [Audio Video](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/CaptureaudioorvideothroughdevicesconnectedtothePC.htm). I found using Google search, I just posted code here in-case link becomes outdated.

```
import javax.media.*;
import javax.media.format.*;
import javax.media.protocol.*;
import java.util.*;

/*******************************************************************************
 * A simple application to allow users to capture audio or video through devices
 * connected to the PC. Via command-line arguments the user specifies whether
 * audio (-a) or video (-v) capture, the duration of the capture (-d) in
 * seconds, and the file to write the media to (-f).
 * 
 * The application would be far more useful and versatile if it provided control
 * over the formats of the audio and video captured as well as the content type
 * of the output.
 * 
 * The class searches for capture devices that support the particular default
 * track formats: linear for audio and Cinepak for video. As a fall-back two
 * device names are hard-coded into the application as an example of how to
 * obtain DeviceInfo when a device's name is known. The user may force the
 * application to use these names by using the -k (known devices) flag.
 * 
 * The class is static but employs the earlier Location2Location example to
 * perform all the Processor and DataSink related work. Thus the application
 * chiefly involves CaptureDevice related operations.
 * 
 * @author Michael (Spike) Barlow
 ******************************************************************************/
public class SimpleRecorder {

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Names for the audio and video capture devices on the
  // author's system. These will vary system to system but are
  // only used as a fallback.
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  private static final String AUDIO_DEVICE_NAME = "DirectSoundCapture";

  private static final String VIDEO_DEVICE_NAME = "vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture:0";

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Default names for the files to write the output to for
  // the case where they are not supplie by the user.
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  private static final String DEFAULT_AUDIO_NAME = "file://./captured.wav";

  private static final String DEFAULT_VIDEO_NAME = "file://./captured.avi";

  ///////////////////////////////////////////
  // Type of capture requested by the user.
  //////////////////////////////////////////
  private static final String AUDIO = "audio";

  private static final String VIDEO = "video";

  private static final String BOTH = "audio and video";

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // The only audio and video formats that the particular application
  // supports. A better program would allow user selection of formats
  // but would grow past the small example size.
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  private static final Format AUDIO_FORMAT = new AudioFormat(
      AudioFormat.LINEAR);

  private static final Format VIDEO_FORMAT = new VideoFormat(
      VideoFormat.CINEPAK);

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Object to handle the processing and sinking of the
    // data captured from the device.
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Location2Location capture;

    /////////////////////////////////////
    // Audio and video capture devices.
    ////////////////////////////////////
    CaptureDeviceInfo audioDevice = null;
    CaptureDeviceInfo videoDevice = null;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Capture device's "location" plus the name and location of
    // the destination.
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    MediaLocator captureLocation = null;
    MediaLocator destinationLocation;
    String destinationName = null;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Formats the Processor (in Location2Location) must match.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Format[] formats = new Format[1];

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Content type for an audio or video capture.
    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    ContentDescriptor audioContainer = new ContentDescriptor(
        FileTypeDescriptor.WAVE);
    ContentDescriptor videoContainer = new ContentDescriptor(
        FileTypeDescriptor.MSVIDEO);
    ContentDescriptor container = null;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Duration of recording (in seconds) and period to wait afterwards
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    double duration = 10;
    int waitFor = 0;

    //////////////////////////
    // Audio or video capture?
    //////////////////////////
    String selected = AUDIO;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // All devices that support the format in question.
    // A means of "ensuring" the program works on different
    // machines with different capture devices.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Vector devices;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Whether to search for capture devices that support the
    // format or use the devices whos names are already
    // known to the application.
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    boolean useKnownDevices = false;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Process the command-line options as to audio or video,
    // duration, and file to save to.
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    for (int i = 0; i  0 && !useKnownDevices) {
        audioDevice = (CaptureDeviceInfo) devices.elementAt(0);
      } else
        audioDevice = CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice(AUDIO_DEVICE_NAME);
      if (audioDevice == null) {
        System.out.println("Can't find suitable audio device. Exiting");
        System.exit(1);
      }
      captureLocation = audioDevice.getLocator();
      formats[0] = AUDIO_FORMAT;
      if (destinationName == null)
        destinationName = DEFAULT_AUDIO_NAME;
      container = audioContainer;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Perform setup for video capture. Includes finding a suitable
    // device, obatining its MediaLocator and setting the content
    // type.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    else if (selected.equals(VIDEO)) {
      devices = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(VIDEO_FORMAT);
      if (devices.size() > 0 && !useKnownDevices)
        videoDevice = (CaptureDeviceInfo) devices.elementAt(0);
      else
        videoDevice = CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice(VIDEO_DEVICE_NAME);
      if (videoDevice == null) {
        System.out.println("Can't find suitable video device. Exiting");
        System.exit(1);
      }
      captureLocation = videoDevice.getLocator();
      formats[0] = VIDEO_FORMAT;
      if (destinationName == null)
        destinationName = DEFAULT_VIDEO_NAME;
      container = videoContainer;
    } else if (selected.equals(BOTH)) {
      captureLocation = null;
      formats = new Format[2];
      formats[0] = AUDIO_FORMAT;
      formats[1] = VIDEO_FORMAT;
      container = videoContainer;
      if (destinationName == null)
        destinationName = DEFAULT_VIDEO_NAME;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Perform all the necessary Processor and DataSink preparation via
    // the Location2Location class.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    destinationLocation = new MediaLocator(destinationName);
    System.out.println("Configuring for capture. Please wait.");
    capture = new Location2Location(captureLocation, destinationLocation,
        formats, container, 1.0);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Start the recording and tell the user. Specify the length of the
    // recording. Then wait around for up to 4-times the duration of
    // recording
    // (can take longer to sink/write the data so should wait a bit incase).
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    System.out.println("Started recording " + duration + " seconds of "
        + selected + " ...");
    capture.setStopTime(new Time(duration));
    if (waitFor == 0)
      waitFor = (int) (4000 * duration);
    else
      waitFor *= 1000;
    int waited = capture.transfer(waitFor);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Report on the success (or otherwise) of the recording.
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int state = capture.getState();
    if (state == Location2Location.FINISHED)
      System.out.println(selected
          + " capture successful in approximately "
          + ((int) ((waited + 500) / 1000))
          + " seconds. Data written to " + destinationName);
    else if (state == Location2Location.FAILED)
      System.out.println(selected
          + " capture failed after approximately "
          + ((int) ((waited + 500) / 1000)) + " seconds");
    else {
      System.out.println(selected
          + " capture still ongoing after approximately "
          + ((int) ((waited + 500) / 1000)) + " seconds");
      System.out.println("Process likely to have failed");
    }

    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```