# Capturing audio streams in JAVA

Tags: java, windows

I am new to Java, and although I have mastered the syntaxes and constructs, I am having difficult time in getting processed digital audio samples from a mic.

What I am trying to achieve is very simple, while in the long run, I am trying to create a very simple spectrogram, but just to understand/master the audio manipulation process I am trying to start from scratch.

---

**Here is my problem**

When a microphone detects a single beep or any sound, I want to capture that binary data, and just simply display it, in its raw format.

---

Is that really too much to ask from JAVA?

I have read about analog/digital signals, FFT, matlab and I have searched many links in so like these one:

[Is there a way of recording audio of streaming broadcast from a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166187/is-there-a-way-of-recording-audio-of-streaming-broadcast-from-a-webpage)

[Working with audio in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966918/working-with-audio-in-java)

[OpenAL playback captured audio data c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886668/openal-playback-captured-audio-data-c)

and the famous introduction from oracle

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html

and this is actually a good tutorial http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3380031/Spectrum-Analysis-using-Java-Sampling-Frequency-Folding-Frequency-and-the-FFT-Algorithm.htm

**But** they all fall short of providing a solution to my answer.

I am not asking for a code, although it would it would be awesome, just to read every line and understand about the mechanics involved, but a simple hint would be nice as well.

---

And here is a simple code, to capture bytes, but only from an existing `wav` file

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Boo{
    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("beep.wav");
            boolean eof = false;
            int count = 0;
            while(!eof){
                int input = file.read();
                System.out.print(input + "");
                if(input == -1)
                    eof = true;
                else 
                    count++;
            }
            file.close();
            System.out.println("\nBytes read: " + count);
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error - " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

### After Bounty

-For better clarity-

All I am trying to make it just a simple program to read from mic. and show the binary data of the sound it caputures in a real time.

Think of it like a spectrogram, when sound is captured the graph goes up and down depending on the variety of the signal level, but in this case, there is no need to convert the binary data to audio graph, just only to show any raw data itself. No need to write/read files. Just capture from mic, and show what is read from the mic.

If the above provides to be difficult, as I have searched all over the web, and couldn't find anything helpful, you can just give me guides/directions..
thanks

Comment: have you tried writing code like is described in the oracle docs?  because that seems to describe what to do pretty clearly.  if you do that, and have a problem, i think posting again describing that problem would get more help.  at the moment you seem to be asking for something very general that is described quite well by the oracle docs, so it's not clear what else to say.  if you tried what was described there and then asked for help with a specific problem i think people would have more idea of how to help.

Comment: @andrewcooke thanks for your reply. I was starting to give up hope.  I am reading the docs, but I found them a bit hard for a beginner and not quite covering a solution for the aformentioned problem

Answer (score 9):

`javax.sound.sampled` package should have all you need.

Example:

```
    int duration = 5; // sample for 5 seconds
    TargetDataLine line = null;
    // find a DataLine that can be read
    // (maybe hardcode this if you have multiple microphones)
    Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i < mixerInfo.length; i++) {
        Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[i]);
        Line.Info[] targetLineInfo = mixer.getTargetLineInfo();
        if (targetLineInfo.length > 0) {
            line = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(targetLineInfo[0]);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (line == null)
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No recording device found");
    AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(11000, 8, 1, true, false);
    line.open(af);
    line.start();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[(int)af.getSampleRate() * af.getFrameSize()];
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * duration;
    int len;
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end && ((len = line.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1)) {
        baos.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    line.stop();
    line.close();
    baos.close();
```

Afterwards, you can dig the bytes out of your byte array output stream. Or you can of course process them inside the `while` loop if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code copy-pasted from Sphinx4 microphone support. I hope it will be useful.

And a link to Sphinx homepage: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/.

```
/**
 * <p/> A Microphone captures audio data from the system's underlying audio input systems. Converts these audio data
 * into Data objects. When the method <code>startRecording()</code> is called, a new thread will be created and used to
 * capture audio, and will stop when <code>stopRecording()</code> is called. Calling <code>getData()</code> returns the
 * captured audio data as Data objects. </p> <p/> This Microphone will attempt to obtain an audio device with the format
 * specified in the configuration. If such a device with that format cannot be obtained, it will try to obtain a device
 * with an audio format that has a higher sample rate than the configured sample rate, while the other parameters of the
 * format (i.e., sample size, endianness, sign, and channel) remain the same. If, again, no such device can be obtained,
 * it flags an error, and a call <code>startRecording</code> returns false. </p>
 */
public class Microphone extends BaseDataProcessor {

    /**
     * The property for the sample rate of the data.
     */
    @S4Integer(defaultValue = 16000)
    public static final String PROP_SAMPLE_RATE = "sampleRate";

    /**
     * The property that specifies whether or not the microphone will release the audio between utterances.  On
     * certain systems (Linux for one), closing and reopening the audio does not work too well. The default is false for
     * Linux systems, true for others.
     */
    @S4Boolean(defaultValue = true)
    public final static String PROP_CLOSE_BETWEEN_UTTERANCES = "closeBetweenUtterances";

    /**
     * The property that specifies the number of milliseconds of audio data to read each time from the underlying
     * Java Sound audio device.
     */
    @S4Integer(defaultValue = 10)
    public final static String PROP_MSEC_PER_READ = "msecPerRead";

    /**
     * The property for the number of bits per value.
     */
    @S4Integer(defaultValue = 16)
    public static final String PROP_BITS_PER_SAMPLE = "bitsPerSample";

    /**
     * The property specifying the number of channels.
     */
    @S4Integer(defaultValue = 1)
    public static final String PROP_CHANNELS = "channels";

    /**
     * The property specify the endianness of the data.
     */
    @S4Boolean(defaultValue = true)
    public static final String PROP_BIG_ENDIAN = "bigEndian";

    /**
     * The property specify whether the data is signed.
     */
    @S4Boolean(defaultValue = true)
    public static final String PROP_SIGNED = "signed";

    /**
     * The property that specifies whether to keep the audio data of an utterance around until the next utterance
     * is recorded.
     */
    @S4Boolean(defaultValue = false)
    public final static String PROP_KEEP_LAST_AUDIO = "keepLastAudio";

    /**
     * The property that specifies how to convert stereo audio to mono. Currently, the possible values are
     * "average", which averages the samples from at each channel, or "selectChannel", which chooses audio only from
     * that channel. If you choose "selectChannel", you should also specify which channel to use with the
     * "selectChannel" property.
     */
    @S4String(defaultValue = "average", range = {"average", "selectChannel"})
    public final static String PROP_STEREO_TO_MONO = "stereoToMono";

    /**
     * The property that specifies the channel to use if the audio is stereo
     */
    @S4Integer(defaultValue = 0)
    public final static String PROP_SELECT_CHANNEL = "selectChannel";

    /**
     * The property that specifies the mixer to use.  The value can be "default," (which means let the
     * AudioSystem decide), "last," (which means select the last Mixer supported by the AudioSystem), which appears to
     * be what is often used for USB headsets, or an integer value which represents the index of the Mixer.Info that is
     * returned by AudioSystem.getMixerInfo(). To get the list of Mixer.Info objects, run the AudioTool application with
     * a command line argument of "-dumpMixers".
     *
     * @see edu.cmu.sphinx.tools.audio.AudioTool
     */
    @S4String(defaultValue = "default")
    public final static String PROP_SELECT_MIXER = "selectMixer";


    private AudioFormat finalFormat;
    private AudioInputStream audioStream;
    private TargetDataLine audioLine;
    private BlockingQueue<Data> audioList;
    private Utterance currentUtterance;
    private boolean doConversion;
    private final int audioBufferSize = 160000;
    private volatile boolean recording;
    private volatile boolean utteranceEndReached = true;
    private RecordingThread recorder;

    // Configuration data

    private AudioFormat desiredFormat;
    private Logger logger;
    private boolean closeBetweenUtterances;
    private boolean keepDataReference;
    private boolean signed;
    private boolean bigEndian;
    private int frameSizeInBytes;
    private int msecPerRead;
    private int selectedChannel;
    private String selectedMixerIndex;
    private String stereoToMono;
    private int sampleRate;

    /**
     * @param sampleRate sample rate of the data
     * @param bitsPerSample number of bits per value.
     * @param channels number of channels.
     * @param bigEndian the endianness of the data
     * @param signed whether the data is signed.
     * @param closeBetweenUtterances whether or not the microphone will release the audio between utterances.  On
     * certain systems (Linux for one), closing and reopening the audio does not work too well. The default is false for
     * Linux systems, true for others
     * @param msecPerRead the number of milliseconds of audio data to read each time from the underlying
     * Java Sound audio device.
     * @param keepLastAudio whether to keep the audio data of an utterance around until the next utterance
     * is recorded.
     * @param stereoToMono how to convert stereo audio to mono. Currently, the possible values are
     * "average", which averages the samples from at each channel, or "selectChannel", which chooses audio only from
     * that channel. If you choose "selectChannel", you should also specify which channel to use with the
     * "selectChannel" property.
     * @param selectedChannel the channel to use if the audio is stereo
     * @param selectedMixerIndex the mixer to use.  The value can be "default," (which means let the
     * AudioSystem decide), "last," (which means select the last Mixer supported by the AudioSystem), which appears to
     * be what is often used for USB headsets, or an integer value which represents the index of the Mixer.Info that is
     * returned by AudioSystem.getMixerInfo(). To get the list of Mixer.Info objects, run the AudioTool application with
     * a command line argument of "-dumpMixers".
     */
    public Microphone(int sampleRate, int bitsPerSample, int channels,
                      boolean bigEndian, boolean signed, boolean closeBetweenUtterances, int msecPerRead, boolean keepLastAudio,
                      String stereoToMono, int selectedChannel, String selectedMixerIndex) {
        initLogger();

        this.bigEndian = bigEndian;
        this.signed = signed;

        this.desiredFormat = new AudioFormat
                ((float) sampleRate, bitsPerSample, channels, signed, bigEndian);

        this.closeBetweenUtterances = closeBetweenUtterances;
        this.msecPerRead = msecPerRead;
        this.keepDataReference = keepLastAudio;
        this.stereoToMono = stereoToMono;
        this.selectedChannel = selectedChannel;
        this.selectedMixerIndex = selectedMixerIndex;
    }

    public Microphone() {

    }

    /*
    * (non-Javadoc)
    *
    * @see edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.Configurable#newProperties(edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet)
    */
    @Override
    public void newProperties(PropertySheet ps) throws PropertyException {
        super.newProperties(ps);
        logger = ps.getLogger();

        sampleRate = ps.getInt(PROP_SAMPLE_RATE);

        int sampleSizeInBits = ps.getInt(PROP_BITS_PER_SAMPLE);

        int channels = ps.getInt(PROP_CHANNELS);
        bigEndian = ps.getBoolean(PROP_BIG_ENDIAN);
        signed = ps.getBoolean(PROP_SIGNED);

        desiredFormat = new AudioFormat
                ((float) sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, bigEndian);

        closeBetweenUtterances = ps.getBoolean(PROP_CLOSE_BETWEEN_UTTERANCES);
        msecPerRead = ps.getInt(PROP_MSEC_PER_READ);
        keepDataReference = ps.getBoolean(PROP_KEEP_LAST_AUDIO);
        stereoToMono = ps.getString(PROP_STEREO_TO_MONO);
        selectedChannel = ps.getInt(PROP_SELECT_CHANNEL);
        selectedMixerIndex = ps.getString(PROP_SELECT_MIXER);
    }


    /**
     * Constructs a Microphone with the given InputStream.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize() {
        super.initialize();
        audioList = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Data>();

        DataLine.Info info
                = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, desiredFormat);

        /* If we cannot get an audio line that matches the desired
         * characteristics, shoot for one that matches almost
         * everything we want, but has a higher sample rate.
         */
        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
            logger.info(desiredFormat + " not supported");
            AudioFormat nativeFormat
                    = DataUtil.getNativeAudioFormat(desiredFormat,
                    getSelectedMixer());
            if (nativeFormat == null) {
                logger.severe("couldn't find suitable target audio format");
            } else {
                finalFormat = nativeFormat;

                /* convert from native to the desired format if supported */
                doConversion = AudioSystem.isConversionSupported
                        (desiredFormat, nativeFormat);

                if (doConversion) {
                    logger.info
                            ("Converting from " + finalFormat.getSampleRate()
                                    + "Hz to " + desiredFormat.getSampleRate() + "Hz");
                } else {
                    logger.info
                            ("Using native format: Cannot convert from " +
                                    finalFormat.getSampleRate() + "Hz to " +
                                    desiredFormat.getSampleRate() + "Hz");
                }
            }
        } else {
            logger.info("Desired format: " + desiredFormat + " supported.");
            finalFormat = desiredFormat;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Gets the Mixer to use.  Depends upon selectedMixerIndex being defined.
     *
     * @see #newProperties
     */
    private Mixer getSelectedMixer() {
        if (selectedMixerIndex.equals("default")) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
            if (selectedMixerIndex.equals("last")) {
                return AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[mixerInfo.length - 1]);
            } else {
                int index = Integer.parseInt(selectedMixerIndex);
                return AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[index]);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Creates the audioLine if necessary and returns it.
     */
    private TargetDataLine getAudioLine() {
        if (audioLine != null) {
            return audioLine;
        }

        /* Obtain and open the line and stream.
        */
        try {
            /* The finalFormat was decided in the initialize() method
             * and is based upon the capabilities of the underlying
             * audio system.  The final format will have all the
             * desired audio characteristics, but may have a sample
             * rate that is higher than desired.  The idea here is
             * that we'll let the processors in the front end (e.g.,
             * the FFT) handle some form of downsampling for us.
             */
            logger.info("Final format: " + finalFormat);

            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class,
                    finalFormat);

            /* We either get the audio from the AudioSystem (our
             * default choice), or use a specific Mixer if the
             * selectedMixerIndex property has been set.
             */
            Mixer selectedMixer = getSelectedMixer();
            if (selectedMixer == null) {
                audioLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            } else {
                audioLine = (TargetDataLine) selectedMixer.getLine(info);
            }

            /* Add a line listener that just traces
             * the line states.
             */
            audioLine.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
                @Override
                public void update(LineEvent event) {
                    logger.info("line listener " + event);
                }
            });
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            logger.severe("microphone unavailable " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return audioLine;
    }


    /**
     * Opens the audio capturing device so that it will be ready for capturing audio. Attempts to create a converter if
     * the requested audio format is not directly available.
     *
     * @return true if the audio capturing device is opened successfully; false otherwise
     */
    private boolean open() {
        TargetDataLine audioLine = getAudioLine();
        if (audioLine != null) {
            if (!audioLine.isOpen()) {
                logger.info("open");
                try {
                    audioLine.open(finalFormat, audioBufferSize);
                } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                    logger.severe("Can't open microphone " + e.getMessage());
                    return false;
                }

                audioStream = new AudioInputStream(audioLine);
                if (doConversion) {
                    audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream
                            (desiredFormat, audioStream);
                    assert (audioStream != null);
                }

                /* Set the frame size depending on the sample rate.
                 */
                float sec = ((float) msecPerRead) / 1000.f;
                frameSizeInBytes =
                        (audioStream.getFormat().getSampleSizeInBits() / 8) *
                                (int) (sec * audioStream.getFormat().getSampleRate());

                logger.info("Frame size: " + frameSizeInBytes + " bytes");
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            logger.severe("Can't find microphone");
            return false;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Returns the format of the audio recorded by this Microphone. Note that this might be different from the
     * configured format.
     *
     * @return the current AudioFormat
     */
    public AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
        return finalFormat;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the current Utterance.
     *
     * @return the current Utterance
     */
    public Utterance getUtterance() {
        return currentUtterance;
    }


    /**
     * Returns true if this Microphone is recording.
     *
     * @return true if this Microphone is recording, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isRecording() {
        return recording;
    }


    /**
     * Starts recording audio. This method will return only when a START event is received, meaning that this Microphone
     * has started capturing audio.
     *
     * @return true if the recording started successfully; false otherwise
     */
    public synchronized boolean startRecording() {
        if (recording) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!open()) {
            return false;
        }
        utteranceEndReached = false;
        if (audioLine.isRunning()) {
            logger.severe("Whoops: audio line is running");
        }
        assert (recorder == null);
        recorder = new RecordingThread("Microphone");
        recorder.start();
        recording = true;
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Stops recording audio. This method does not return until recording has been stopped and all data has been read
     * from the audio line.
     */
    public synchronized void stopRecording() {
        if (audioLine != null) {
            if (recorder != null) {
                recorder.stopRecording();
                recorder = null;
            }
            recording = false;
        }
    }


    /**
     * This Thread records audio, and caches them in an audio buffer.
     */
    class RecordingThread extends Thread {

        private boolean done;
        private volatile boolean started;
        private long totalSamplesRead;
        private final Object lock = new Object();


        /**
         * Creates the thread with the given name
         *
         * @param name the name of the thread
         */
        public RecordingThread(String name) {
            super(name);
        }


        /**
         * Starts the thread, and waits for recorder to be ready
         */
        @Override
        public void start() {
            started = false;
            super.start();
            waitForStart();
        }


        /**
         * Stops the thread. This method does not return until recording has actually stopped, and all the data has been
         * read from the audio line.
         */
        public void stopRecording() {
            audioLine.stop();
            try {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    while (!done) {
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // flush can not be called here because the audio-line might has been set to  null already by the mic-thread 
//          audioLine.flush();
        }


        /**
         * Implements the run() method of the Thread class. Records audio, and cache them in the audio buffer.
         */
        @Override
        public void run() {
            totalSamplesRead = 0;
            logger.info("started recording");

            if (keepDataReference) {
                currentUtterance = new Utterance
                        ("Microphone", audioStream.getFormat());
            }

            audioList.add(new DataStartSignal(sampleRate));
            logger.info("DataStartSignal added");
            try {
                audioLine.start();
                while (!done) {
                    Data data = readData(currentUtterance);
                    if (data == null) {
                        done = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    audioList.add(data);
                }
                audioLine.flush();
                if (closeBetweenUtterances) {
                    /* Closing the audio stream *should* (we think)
                     * also close the audio line, but it doesn't
                     * appear to do this on the Mac.  In addition,
                     * once the audio line is closed, re-opening it
                     * on the Mac causes some issues.  The Java sound
                     * spec is also kind of ambiguous about whether a
                     * closed line can be re-opened.  So...we'll go
                     * for the conservative route and never attempt
                     * to re-open a closed line.
                     */
                    audioStream.close();
                    audioLine.close();
                    System.err.println("set to null");
                    audioLine = null;
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                logger.warning("IO Exception " + ioe.getMessage());
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            long duration = (long)
                    (((double) totalSamplesRead /
                            (double) audioStream.getFormat().getSampleRate()) * 1000.0);

            audioList.add(new DataEndSignal(duration));
            logger.info("DataEndSignal ended");
            logger.info("stopped recording");

            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.notify();
            }
        }


        /**
         * Waits for the recorder to start
         */
        private synchronized void waitForStart() {
            // note that in theory we coulde use a LineEvent START
            // to tell us when the microphone is ready, but we have
            // found that some javasound implementations do not always
            // issue this event when a line  is opened, so this is a
            // WORKAROUND.

            try {
                while (!started) {
                    wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                logger.warning("wait was interrupted");
            }
        }


        /**
         * Reads one frame of audio data, and adds it to the given Utterance.
         *
         * @param utterance
         * @return an Data object containing the audio data
         * @throws java.io.IOException
         */
        private Data readData(Utterance utterance) throws IOException {

            // Read the next chunk of data from the TargetDataLine.
            byte[] data = new byte[frameSizeInBytes];

            int channels = audioStream.getFormat().getChannels();
            long collectTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long firstSampleNumber = totalSamplesRead / channels;

            int numBytesRead = audioStream.read(data, 0, data.length);

            //  notify the waiters upon start
            if (!started) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    started = true;
                    notifyAll();
                }
            }

            if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
                logger.info("Read " + numBytesRead
                        + " bytes from audio stream.");
            }
            if (numBytesRead <= 0) {
                return null;
            }
            int sampleSizeInBytes =
                    audioStream.getFormat().getSampleSizeInBits() / 8;
            totalSamplesRead += (numBytesRead / sampleSizeInBytes);

            if (numBytesRead != frameSizeInBytes) {

                if (numBytesRead % sampleSizeInBytes != 0) {
                    throw new Error("Incomplete sample read.");
                }

                data = Arrays.copyOf(data, numBytesRead);
            }

            if (keepDataReference) {
                utterance.add(data);
            }

            double[] samples;

            if (bigEndian) {
                samples = DataUtil.bytesToValues
                        (data, 0, data.length, sampleSizeInBytes, signed);
            } else {
                samples = DataUtil.littleEndianBytesToValues
                        (data, 0, data.length, sampleSizeInBytes, signed);
            }

            if (channels > 1) {
                samples = convertStereoToMono(samples, channels);
            }

            return (new DoubleData
                    (samples, (int) audioStream.getFormat().getSampleRate(),
                            collectTime, firstSampleNumber));
        }
    }


    /**
     * Converts stereo audio to mono.
     *
     * @param samples  the audio samples, each double in the array is one sample
     * @param channels the number of channels in the stereo audio
     */
    private double[] convertStereoToMono(double[] samples, int channels) {
        assert (samples.length % channels == 0);
        double[] finalSamples = new double[samples.length / channels];
        if (stereoToMono.equals("average")) {
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < samples.length; j++) {
                double sum = samples[i++];
                for (int c = 1; c < channels; c++) {
                    sum += samples[i++];
                }
                finalSamples[j] = sum / channels;
            }
        } else if (stereoToMono.equals("selectChannel")) {
            for (int i = selectedChannel, j = 0; i < samples.length;
                 i += channels, j++) {
                finalSamples[j] = samples[i];
            }
        } else {
            throw new Error("Unsupported stereo to mono conversion: " +
                    stereoToMono);
        }
        return finalSamples;
    }


    /**
     * Clears all cached audio data.
     */
    public void clear() {
        audioList.clear();
    }


    /**
     * Reads and returns the next Data object from this Microphone, return null if there is no more audio data. All
     * audio data captured in-between <code>startRecording()</code> and <code>stopRecording()</code> is cached in an
     * Utterance object. Calling this method basically returns the next chunk of audio data cached in this Utterance.
     *
     * @return the next Data or <code>null</code> if none is available
     */
    @Override
    public Data getData() throws DataProcessingException {
        getTimer().start();

        Data output = null;

        if (!utteranceEndReached) {
            try {
                output = audioList.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                throw new DataProcessingException("cannot take Data from audioList", ie);
            }
            if (output instanceof DataEndSignal) {
                utteranceEndReached = true;
            }
        }

        getTimer().stop();

        // signalCheck(output);

        return output;
    }


    /**
     * Returns true if there is more data in the Microphone.
     * This happens either if the a DataEndSignal data was not taken from the buffer,
     * or if the buffer in the Microphone is not yet empty.
     *
     * @return true if there is more data in the Microphone
     */
    public boolean hasMoreData() {
        return !(utteranceEndReached && audioList.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sphinx4 is definitely what you want for this.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/public/documentation/java/api/).  They dropped support for the project but it still has all the documentation and the [google-group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/xuggler-users) will sometimes give you a good answer.

As for specifically reading audio off hardware, start with these [demos](https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/tree/master/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/demos) and work your way from there.

The hardest part about this is streaming the data from your mic, which is pretty well explained in the [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html) you linked.

So stream it into xuggle using the oracle docs, then manipulate the audio how you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't try followings, I just post them for just helping you. you may try those and may help you.

[Record streaming audio in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351582/record-streaming-audio-in-java)

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11942/CS_recording_audio_from_a_player_740038_11.jsp

http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/12/java-sound-capture-from-microphone.html

http://edenti.deis.unibo.it/utils/Java-tips/Capturing%20Audio%20with%20Java%20Sound%20API.txt

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html